# Xcode: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Tags: xcode, swift, ios9

Xcode error: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

How do I fix it?

```
let componentss = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitYear | .CalendarUnitMonth | .CalendarUnitDay | .CalendarUnitHour | .CalendarUnitMinute | .CalendarUnitSecond, fromDate: date)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`CalendarUnit` name has changed in Swift 2.0. Try this:

```
let componentss = calendar.components([.Year, .Month, .Day, .Hour, .Minute, .Second], fromDate: date)
```

Comment: Okey it works, but this time, there was another error:                                  let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let sec = cal.components(.CalendarUnitSecond, fromDate: startDate, toDate: endDate, options: [])

Comment: There's no more `.CalendarUnitSecond`. Change that to `[.Second]`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks it works!

```
dateFormat.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
dateFormat.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.DateAndTime
datePicker.addTarget(self, action: Selector("updateDateField:"),forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
yearLabel.inputView = datePicker
```

How do I convert this to **dd-MM-yyyy H:mm:ss** ?